# CGI PHP server any examples availble windows

Tags: php, windows

It not hard to write in C++ some support statements to PHP with a DLL as I need them.

Is it possible for me to view a copy of a web server with its own CGI scripts made from PHP, which I can use as an example from somewhere?  I'm doing this for web site security reasons as I know my site will be attacked because of jealousy reasons. Apache simply does not offer the restrictive control I need (yet it’s a good product).
Does anyone know of any examples please?  It would be good to stay in PHP if it’s possible or I convert it to PHP my self.

I want to use the HTML post statment heavly with just a few entry pages to the site.
I'm looking at googles SSL a bit can be a nice addtion.

thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is confusing.. What are you asking?

Comment: If you are suggesting that a PHP extension will be more secure than actual PHP code, you are mistaken. A lapse in security is the fault of the programmer not the language.

Comment: With hard C++ code on its entance and exit will make a fire wall. and giving selected requests secures the site. PHP needs something to offer it a thread for it to work. What i need is details of how a cgi scrpt is implemented first. What port does a cgi work on is far more helpfull. And something on cgi's implemention.

Answer (score 0):

Writing your own web server in PHP is not going to improve your site's security or reliability. It's much more likely to do the opposite.